# How do I access a recovery partition after installing a new OS?

Tags: windows-7, lenovo-laptop

I want to install another OS on my Lenovo laptop, but I don't want to lose the recovery option. This system uses Windows 7's built-in recovery capability, which is accessed by `F8` as an additional option to all standard Windows recovery tools/options.

Said recovery partition contains 2 `.WIM` files (plus some `INI`s etc), which by my short research are a new Microsoft standard for partition images, and can be created with their deployment tool. So it seems to me that this recovery partition, though customized, should be fairly standard.

Inside the partition itself there is only one `EXE` file, and its sole function seems to be creating recovery DVDs (not happening!), so the recovery module must reside somewhere else.

How do I access recovery after formatting?
How can I backup files/configurations needed for this?